# Apply native induction principle in coq with several arguments

Tags: coq, induction

I'm reading the book Software Foundation. On the chapter "More on Induction", the authors talk about the induction principle generated by coq when a inductive type is define.

An exercice is the following. Encapsulate the notion of association for "+" in a definition and then apply the nat_ind on it.

My first guess for the definition was the following :

```
Definition P_plusassoc (n m o:nat) : Prop :=
  n + (m+ o) = (n+m) +o.
```

But then, I have the problem when I want to proof this :

```
Theorem plus_assoct : forall o m n, P_plusassoc n m o.
Proof.
  apply nat_ind.
```

`nat_ind` doesn't work. So I thought it was because `P_plusassoc` does not depend of just one integer but three.

So I rewrite `P_plusassoc` this way :

```
Definition P_plusassoc (n:nat) : nat->nat->Prop :=
      fun (m o:nat) => n + (m+ o) = (n+m) +o.
```

But it still doesn't work. Where is the problem ? How can I define `P_plusassoc` to use `nat_ind` ?

Answer (score 1):

The book gives an answer after. The definition could be :

```
Definition P_plusassoc (n:nat) : Prop :=
      forall m o, n + (m+ o) = (n+m) +o.
```

Answer (score 0):

The question wants you to prove a lemma. However, you are defining a function. What you should do, is define something of type Prop (like `Definition P_plusassoc (n:nat) : Prop := forall m o, n + (m+ o) = (n+m) +o.`).

Personally, I would define a `Lemma : forall m n o :nat, n+(m+o)=(n+m)+o.` Coq will then allow you to prove this lemma, which you could do via `intros. apply (nat_ind n).`